# Create PHP CURL relay

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I want to create a PHP function which simply gets the contents of another URL and returns it.  However, any parameters passed (as _POST or _GET) to this page should be passed to the destination URL.  I've come up with this so far:

```
function relay($url)
{
     $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
     $contents = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     return $contents;
}
```

Now, is there an easy way to create the $post string?  Do I have to foreach through the associative _REQUEST array and build my string?  Do I need to take any precautions to prevent hacking of my string?

THis feels like the kind of thing that's already included in PHP as a one liner/function, but I can't find it.

Comment: `http_build_query($_POST)` = `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Just add the $_GET side of things to the `$url`

Comment: Also, `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` is [no longer used and is pointless](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blobdiff;f=NEWS;h=7028faf2500381b61bada2c9f1ac50c4a25339c5;hp=2e83f29921f180ae55382f061e1fd48a1a664626;hb=33d3eb1e43134deb3e108108f62febdabc8a0aa1;hpb=aeaa4b3da6261b87bae2f80b8507f9081ca4cd55)

Comment: zanderwar - that's what I was looking for thx